# Managing a KML Linestring properties

Tags: kml

I am plotting a LineString.  For some reason, I don't seem to effect the LineStyle.  My code looks identical to many examples but no matter what color or width I place in the LineStyle, it always comes out as a thick blue line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Qtr Min Grid Maker</name>
    <LookAt>
      <longitude>-121.5</longitude>
      <latitude>38</latitude>
      <altitude>0</altitude>
      <range>740933.8825924395</range>
      <tilt>0</tilt>
      <heading>0</heading>
    </LookAt>
    <Folder>
      <name>Grids</name>
  <Style id="linestyle1">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7f0000ff</color>
      <width>1</width>
      <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>   
      <Placemark>
        <name>QTR</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <open>1</open>
        <styleUrl>#linestyle1</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
  <coordinates>
-124.75,40,0 
-124.5,40,0 
-124.25,40,0 
-124,40,0 
-123.75,40,0 
-123.5,40,0 
-123.25,40,0 
-123,40,0 
  </coordinates>
  </LineString>
  </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: How do you plot it? Your kml is valid.

Comment: I get a [syntax error](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20160510_polylineStyle.kml), but [KmlLayer seems to be able to display it](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160510_polylineStyle.kml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me if I move the shared styles to the top level (inside the `<Document>` tag):

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160510_polylineStyle_docColor.kml)

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#elements-specific-to-feature) (see the description of `<StyleSelector>`):

> A style defined within a Feature is called an "inline style" and
>   applies only to the Feature that contains it. **A style defined as the
>   child of a `<Document>` is called a "shared style." A shared style must
>   have an id defined for it. This id is referenced by one or more
>   Features within the `<Document>`.**

Yours is neither a child of `<Document>` nor within a `<Placemark>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
  <Style id="linestyle1">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>7f0000ff</color>
      <width>1</width>
      <gx:labelVisibility>1</gx:labelVisibility>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>   
    <name>Qtr Min Grid Maker</name>
    <LookAt>
      <longitude>-121.5</longitude>
      <latitude>38</latitude>
      <altitude>0</altitude>
      <range>740933.8825924395</range>
      <tilt>0</tilt>
      <heading>0</heading>
    </LookAt>
    <Folder>
      <name>Grids</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>QTR</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <open>1</open>
        <styleUrl>#linestyle1</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
  <coordinates>
-124.75,40,0 
-124.5,40,0 
-124.25,40,0 
-124,40,0 
-123.75,40,0 
-123.5,40,0 
-123.25,40,0 
-123,40,0 
  </coordinates>
  </LineString>
  </Placemark>
  </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```